# How to insert value (random value from List) to sqlite?

Tags: java, android, database, random, type-conversion

I have int values into `List<Integer>`

I created new random - `Random rand = new Random();`

And i can get my random value from this

```
int random_one = givenList.get(rand.nextInt(givenList.size()));
```

But i need to insert `random_one` to the DataBase

As result, i was converted my `random_one` to String

```
String random = Integer.toString(random_one);
```

But it doesn't work again!

I left my code of my MainActivity Class and my DataBase in this order below

I always get answer - Data is not added

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DataBaseHelper myDb;
    EditText name_edittext,age_edittext,weight_edittext,height_edittext;
    Spinner gender_spinner,trauma_spinner,illnesses_spinner;
    Button save;
    String name;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        /*DataBase*/
        myDb = new DataBaseHelper(this);
        /*Spinners*/
        gender_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_gender);
        trauma_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_trauma);
        illnesses_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_illnesses);

        String [] gender={"Male","Female"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> gender_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,gender);
        gender_spinner.setAdapter(gender_adapter);
        String [] trauma={"Back","Hand","Leg","None"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> trauma_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,trauma);
        trauma_spinner.setAdapter(trauma_adapter);
        String [] illnesses={"Heart problems","Scoliosis","Others","None"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> illnesses_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,illnesses);
        illnesses_spinner.setAdapter(illnesses_adapter);
        /*EditTexts*/
        name_edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        age_edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.age);
        weight_edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weight);
        height_edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.height);
        /*Button*/
        save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_button);
        /*Save*/
        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ClickMe();
            }
        });
    }

    private void ClickMe(){
        String name = name_edittext.getText().toString();
        String age = age_edittext.getText().toString();
        String weight = weight_edittext.getText().toString();
        String height = weight_edittext.getText().toString();
        String gender = gender_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String trauma = trauma_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String illnesses = illnesses_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        //Random
        List<Integer> givenList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
        Random rand = new Random();
        int random_one = givenList.get(rand.nextInt(givenList.size()));
        String random = Integer.toString(random_one);

        Boolean result = myDb.insertData(name,age,weight,height,gender,trauma,illnesses,random);
        if (result == true){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Data is added successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Data is not added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        Intent i = new Intent(this,MenuActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

## &&&

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Schedule.dp";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Schedule_table";
    /*Col*/
    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "NAME";
    public static final String COL_3 = "AGE";
    public static final String COL_4 = "WEIGHT";
    public static final String COL_5 = "HEIGHT";
    public static final String COL_6 = "GENDER";
    public static final String COL_7 = "TRAUMA";
    public static final String COL_8 = "ILLNESSES";
    public static final String COL_9 = "RANDOM";

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT,AGE INTEGER,WEIGHT INTEGER,HEIGHT INTEGER,GENDER TEXT,TRAUMA TEXT,ILLNESSES TEXT,RANDOM TEXT)");
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ TABLE_NAME);
    }

    public boolean updataData(String id,String name,String age,String weight,String height,String gender,String trauma,String illnesses,String random){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2,name);
        contentValues.put(COL_3,age);
        contentValues.put(COL_4,weight);
        contentValues.put(COL_5,height);
        contentValues.put(COL_6,gender);
        contentValues.put(COL_7,trauma);
        contentValues.put(COL_8,illnesses);
        contentValues.put(COL_9,random);
        int result = db.update(TABLE_NAME,contentValues,"ID =?",new String[]{id});
        if (result>0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }
    public boolean insertData(String name,String age,String weight,String height,String gender,String trauma,String illnesses,String random){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2,name);
        contentValues.put(COL_3,age);
        contentValues.put(COL_4,weight);
        contentValues.put(COL_5,height);
        contentValues.put(COL_6,gender);
        contentValues.put(COL_7,trauma);
        contentValues.put(COL_8,illnesses);
        contentValues.put(COL_9,random);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
        db.close();
        if (result==-1){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }

    }
    public Cursor getAllData(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("Select * from "+ TABLE_NAME,null);
        return res;
    }
    public void deleteAll(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("delete from "+ TABLE_NAME);
        db.close();
    }
}
```

#### LogCats

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) table Schedule_table has no column named RANDOM
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting ILLNESSES=None NAME=yo AGE=39 WEIGHT=130 RANDOM=1 GENDER=Male HEIGHT=130 TRAUMA=Back
                  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Schedule_table has no column named RANDOM (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Schedule_table(ILLNESSES,NAME,AGE,WEIGHT,RANDOM,GENDER,HEIGHT,TRAUMA) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:893)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:504)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1492)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1364)
                      at adais.myway.data.DataBaseHelper.insertData(DataBaseHelper.java:66)
                      at adais.myway.MainActivity.ClickMe(MainActivity.java:81)
                      at adais.myway.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:22)
                      at adais.myway.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:60)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4463)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18789)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what is the actual problem

Comment: I need to insert all my data, but my insert method doesn't work

Comment: `table Schedule_table has no column named RANDOM` seems clear explanation of your problem. You ware trying to insert some value (regardless of what it was) into column which doesn't exist in specified table. You need to ask yourself first "where specifically do I want to place my random value?".

Comment: But i have column?

Comment: Maybe i'm a beginner, but i see a column. When i created a table, i was creating a TEXT RANDOM. Can you tell me a lot ?

Comment: Are you sure that that column was given *precisely* that name? Or maybe RANDOM is reserved keyword (like for randomizing method) and to turn off that special meaning you need to surround it with some quotes (`\``, `"`, `'`)? (sorry I am not android nor sqlite dev so all my help is basically guessing).

Comment: I resolved this problem. It easy) You should to delete all cash of program if you opened it before and created new schedule. Because, i add new column) Don't worry so, be more quiet. I'm not android nor sqlite dev, too - i'm a beginner.

Comment: But, Thanks - you are good helper)